# How to block execution until user selects row in UITableView which is in a UIPopover?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uipopover

**UPDATED -** have an app that displays a list of files for the user to select from;  the list of files is in a UITableView which is in a UIPopover.  This is the code that displays a UIPopover of the contents of a list of files; the user is expected to pick one of the files at which point processing will continue.  Right now, processing continues *without* the user picking a file from the list, which makes no sense (can't process a file unless I know which file to process!):

```
-(void)browseDirectory {

CommonMethods *cm = [[CommonMethods alloc]init];
fileList = [cm listContentsOfDirectory];

//  format popover to display fileList
UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIView* popoverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 340, 400)];
popoverView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xFFF9AF);
popoverContent.view = popoverView;

//resize the popover view shown in the current view to the view's size
popoverContent.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(340, 400);

//  create a UITableView to display the contents of the array
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:popoverView.frame style:UITableViewStylePlain];

// must set delegate & dataSource, otherwise the the table will be empty and not responsive
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;

// add to canvas
[popoverView addSubview:tableView];

//  if previous popoverController is still visible... dismiss it
if ([popoverController isPopoverVisible])
    [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

//create a popover controller
popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:((UIButton *)oUpload).frame inView:self.view
                 permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
}

// number of section(s), now I assume there is only 1 section
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)theTableView  {

return 1;
}

// number of row in the section, I assume there is only 1 row
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section  {

return fileList.count;
}

// the cell will be returned to the tableView
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"FilenameCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = fileList[indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```

This is the code where -browseDirectory is called:

```
    [self browseDirectory];  //  drops through!

if(cbvABE.checked == YES)  {  //  tab-delimited
    [self createTabExportFile: @"ABE"];  {
        cbvEmailABE.checked? [self sendViaEmail:@"ABE"]:[self uploadToABE];
    }
}
```

The question is:  how do I prevent (or block) the execution from continuing after I call -browseDirectory until the user has selected a row in the UITableView?

Comment: I don't understand what you need. You have some code, which you need to explain what it does - no one wants to read a block of code with no explanation - and you want something, but your don't describe what you want and what goes wrong. Please update your question with more info

Comment: Clarified the question; please remove the down-vote.

Comment: Removed. Will answer it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your processing code to

```
tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
```

This will be called by the table view when a user selects a cell. You can get the selected file using the `row` property of the `indexPath` as index of the file array.

Comment: Unbelievable!  I guess I was too involved to even think of that!  Thank you... let me give it a go and I'll get back to you... thanks again.

Comment: Cheers. No worries, sometimes we miss the most obvious of things, and we need a second pair of eyes. Happy coding.

Comment: I have to wait a few days to award the bounty!  Well deserved!  I have been working on this for 4 days now, and it's finally working like a champ!  Can't thank you enough!  SD